# How to display the name of the zipped file

Tags: linux, unix

The following command zips all files ending in .log over a particular size.

```
sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +100000 -name "*.log" -exec gzip {}
```

But how do I get the output of it to display the name of the zipped files.

I tried the below command, but that didn't work.

```
sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +100000 -name "*.log" -exec gzip -v {} | |awk '{print $6}' \;
```

This is because if you use the -v option for gzip there is a field which returns the name of the zipped file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will show the name of the zipped files:

```
sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +100000 -name "*.log" -exec gzip -v {} \; 2>&1 | awk '{print $6}'
```

This will show the output of gzip:

```
sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +100000 -name "*.log" -exec gzip -v {} \;
```

This will show the original file:

```
sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +100000 -name "*.log" -exec gzip {} \; -exec echo {} \;
```

Comment: why do you need to redirect error, if I take away 2>&1 and just do sudo find / -xdev -type f -size +100000 -name "*.log" -exec gzip -v {} \; | awk '{print $6}', it prints the whole thing, why does redirecting errors stop this?

Comment: gzip -v prints the output to the stderr because it supports redirecting the compressed file to stdout. And if it writes also the -v info to stdout, it will invalidate the stdout.